# Linux (Debian) on a Surface Pro 8

Tags: linux, debian-installer, parrotsec, surface

I have been investigating for a few days if I can install a Linux distro (Preferably Debian) what I have seen so far is information on the Surface Pro 7 I do not know to what extent it is different or I may have problems due to drivers or something, if anyone knows distribution that is good or recommendable I would appreciate it... thank you very much in advance

Comment: found on a search engine by typing "linux surface pro 8" as first hit:  https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface -> https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix

Comment: It's fine, but I was looking for the experience of someone who has managed to do it and if they have been able to have the functionalities as close to 100% @A.B

Comment: Debian has a very old kernel while the Surface Pro requires a ton of quirks in the kernel to work properly. Your best bet is a bleeding edge distro, e.g. Fedora or Arch. Fedora is actually quite a decent and stable distro. You could give it a try.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Okeey, thwU

Answer (score 0):

currently in some surface pro 8 computers the operating system based on linux that works very well is Ubuntu, almost all keyboards are compatible, it is also worth looking at this [github](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface) repository that can help us with those of us who have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Debian stable with non free worked for me to get things going on a surface pro 7+.  Wifi did not work without non free.